# What is the technical name for the steering wheel adjustment lever?

Tags: steering-wheel

Does it have a more accurate name, or is it just to be referred to as the steering wheel adjustment lever for all time?

Comment: I'm really not sure which part you are talking about. Can you better describe where this part is at and/or what it looks like? I realize it has something to do with the steering, but am not even sure what you are talking about, lol.

Comment: He's talking about the steering wheel tilt adjustment lever/switch. http://www.hyundaisonatamanual.com/images/pages/3/page.h49.png

Comment: @Ben, yes, that's the component!

Comment: @Ben - make that the answer, Brother!! :o)

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment from @Ben, it's called the "steering wheel tilt/telescope adjustment lever".

Not trying to steal anyone's thunder, just getting this question off the 'unanswered question' list c:

Comment: in UK its referred to as a "Reach/Rake adjustment lever", some cars only allow for Rake adjustment, some only allow Reach.